# Iterating data frame

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I want to merge column in csv by sub string. For this I have prepared an example, where I collected the columns which is contains the sub string. As a second step I merge them in one column, and in the end I will append the new column to the final csv.

But I have a problem with iteration.

```
a <- clickstreamwithoutday
a <- clickstreamwithoutday %>% select(contains("li"))
n <- as.numeric(ncol(a))
sep <- "/"
b <- as.data.frame ( (apply( a[ , c(1:n) ] , 1 , paste0 , collapse = sep)),
                     col.names = names("li"), stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

#append *b* to the csv ... (at the moment I dont know how )
```

For this I get this message:

> Error in apply(a[, c(1:n)], 1, paste0, collapse = sep) : dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: can you give a small example of `clickstreamwithoutday` and an expected output?

Comment: it is a simple csv, where column name is a webpage link, and rows are contain number of clicks which is created by users

Comment: your code works fine on my simple example: `clickstreamwithoutday <- data_frame(link1 = 0:5, link2=10:15, page3=100:105)`

Comment: The dataframe was the problem.. **class(clickstreamwithoutday)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"** . I changed this **a <- data.frame(clickstreamwithoutday %>% select(contains("course")))** , and it is working